# Django 1.3 and Django 1.4 on the same development machine/server

Tags: django

Anyone had any problems with installing django 1.3 and 1.4 on the same development machine next to each other? Developing project A with django 1.3 and project B with django 1.4?

Anyone tryed to run different applications with different versions of django on the same server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/).

Comment: and [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) to make your life even easier

Comment: Even without virtualenv it shouldn't be a problem. It is just a matter of setting up your `PYTHONPATH` correctly. But virtualenv makes it easier as it also integrates well with pip.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have 1.3 and 1.4 installed. There is no any problem if you use virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/)